# Embedded Navigation Controller bar not showing

Tags: uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm attempting to show another TableViewController which has an embedded Navigation Controller. However, when I attempt to run the simulation, it isn't showing the Navigation Controller.

I've attached some of the screenshots

My code for AlertTableViewController.swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject] {


    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
        title: "Delete",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            // Delete the row from the data source
    } )



    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
        title: "Edit",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            // Delete the row from the data source

            let wlObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AlertScheduleList

            let editDestinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editWLVC") as! EditWLTableViewController
            editDestinationController.watchlist = wlObject
            self.presentViewController(editDestinationController, animated: true, completion: nil )

    } )

    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 126.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}
```

My storyboard for the AlertTableViewController

[image]

The simulation result when I run it

[image]

Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your simulator landscape mode?

Comment: yes, landscape mode... even if it is in portrait mode, still showing the same problem tho

Answer (score 0):

Check here, I guess you have checked any of Hide Bars options

[image]